# How to import json objects in HDFS(Hive) to Mysql

Tags: hive, hdfs, sqoop

I have tried sqoop but it gives Text mapper error.

The json object contains nested fields. How to export this data to MYSQL from hive (HDFS) ?

```
{"Numberoffollowers":"77","Description":"A.C. Telezone - Tata Photon Plus in Delhi & NCR\n\n\nA.C. Telezone believe in providing the best suited plan for Tata Photon Plus in Delhi & NCR, after understanding the clients requirement &  getting the best time to time offers to our clients.\n\nTata Photon Plus in Delhi & NCR is a High Speed Internet Access Service in the form of a USB Modem offered by Tata Teleservices Ltd.\n\nTata Photon+ in Delhi/NCR the next generation technology offers a great mobile internet connectivity solution. Tata Photon Plus now gives access to the internet at never before speeds.\n\nFree Home Delivery -  Tata  Photon Plus in Delhi & Ncr\n\nA C Telezone is a wholesale dealer offering Tata Photon Plus in Delhi & NCR.\n\nTata Photon Plus in Delhi & NCR for Desktop and Laptop.\nStay connected wherever you go with Tata Photon Plus in Delhi & NCR.\n\nAdvantage of using the Tata Photon Plus in Delhi & NCR:\n\n\u2022Enjoy Superior Indoor Connectivity\n\u2022Free Roaming anywhere in India\n\u2022Dedicated Data Carrier\n\u2022Enhanced Signal Reception\n\u2022Just 3 Mouse Clicks Simple Activation process\n\u2022Photon Plus Coverage now in Delhi & NCR\n\u2022Photon Care \u2013 Dedicated Photon Call Centre\n\u2022100% Cash Back Offer\n\nFree Delivery on call, Tata Photon Plus in Delhi & NCR\n\nTata Photon Plus Offers Affordable plans to suit your needs for everyone in Delhi & NCR.\n\nFor Special Offers and Free Home Delivery of Tata Photon Plus in Delhi & NCR\n\nContact:\nShakti Kalra\n9210450000\nA.C.Telezone\nCSP/Franchisee- TTSL\nNew Delhi.\nhttp://www.actelezone.com/","EmployeeCountRange ":"C,11-50","Locations":[{"street2":"","regionCode":"7151","street1":"New Delhi","postalCode":"110001","state":"Delhi","countryCode":"in","city":"New Delhi"}],"WebsiteUrl":"http://www.actelezone.com/","Name":"A.C. Telezone - Tata Photon Plus in Delhi & NCR","Status":"Operating","TwitterId":"","searchName":"A & C Wholesale","Foundedyear":"2009","ContactInfo":[{"fax":"","phone2":"","phone1":"+919210450000"}],"Blog":"","EmailDomains":"[actelezone.com]","Specialities":"[Tata Photon Plus in Delhi & NCR, Tata Photon Plus in Delhi, Tata Photon Plus in Delhi & NCR - Internet Services]","Industry":"Internet"},

sqoop-export --connect jdbc:mysql://****/HIVE_DATA --username user --password user --table linkedin_source  --export-dir --username user --password user /user/hive/warehouse/linkedin_source/

the error is Warning: /usr/lib/hbase does not exist! HBase imports will fail.
Please set $HBASE_HOME to the root of your HBase installation.
Warning: /usr/lib/hcatalog does not exist! HCatalog jobs will fail.
Please set $HCAT_HOME to the root of your HCatalog installation.
Warning: $HADOOP_HOME is deprecated.

14/02/13 12:48:10 WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead.
14/02/13 12:48:11 INFO manager.MySQLManager: Preparing to use a MySQL streaming resultset.
14/02/13 12:48:11 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation
14/02/13 12:48:17 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM `linkedin_source` AS t LIMIT 1
14/02/13 12:48:18 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM `linkedin_source` AS t LIMIT 1
14/02/13 12:48:18 INFO orm.CompilationManager: HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME is /hive/Hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1
Note: /tmp/sqoop-root/compile/56ea92df7c4494a3bad2e614859f19e1/linkedin_source.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
14/02/13 12:48:32 INFO orm.CompilationManager: Writing jar file: /tmp/sqoop-root/compile/56ea92df7c4494a3bad2e614859f19e1/linkedin_source.jar
14/02/13 12:48:33 INFO mapreduce.ExportJobBase: Beginning export of linkedin_source
14/02/13 12:48:48 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 6
14/02/13 12:48:48 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 6
14/02/13 12:48:49 INFO util.NativeCodeLoader: Loaded the native-hadoop library
14/02/13 12:48:49 WARN snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library not loaded
14/02/13 12:48:51 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201402121526_0075
14/02/13 12:48:52 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
14/02/13 12:59:46 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201402121526_0075_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
java.io.IOException: Can't export data, please check task tracker logs
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:112)
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:39)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:145)
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.AutoProgressMapper.run(AutoProgressMapper.java:64)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:764)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:364)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException
        at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:834)
        at linkedin_source.__loadFromFields(linkedin_source.java:909)
        at linkedin_source.parse(linkedin_source.java:768)
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:83)
        ... 10 more
```

This is the error i got. How to solve this error. Is this due to nested json object present in HDFS ?

Answer (score 0):

Use JsonSerde - a read/write SerDe for JSON Data. This module allows hive to read and write in JSON format.

- **Useful links:**
- http://code.google.com/p/hive-json-serde/wiki/GettingStarted
- https://github.com/rcongiu/Hive-JSON-Serde

Comment: No newTag git hub link you have given is to create external table for json data in hive but still data will be in HDFS only, hive is only schema, my requirement is to move data present in HDFS(hive) to mysql.

Comment: Ok. Can you post the error you are getting while you are using sqoop??

Comment: newTag i have posted error in my question itself, please go through it.